# Number of workers on the Apache 2.2 status page (Scoreboard)

Tags: linux, debian, configuration, apache-2.2, mpm-prefork

I installed Apache 2.2 from the Debian repository (6.0/Squeeze). By default, Debian installs the prefork module and comes with the following (default) configuration:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
  StartServers          5
  MinSpareServers       5
  MaxSpareServers      10
  MaxClients          150
  MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

Looking at the scoreboard on the status page, I see there are 256 workers available:

```
Current Time: Sunday, 05-Jun-2011 22:50:00 CEST
Restart Time: Saturday, 04-Jun-2011 05:49:50 CEST
Parent Server Generation: 3
Server uptime: 1 day 17 hours 9 seconds
Total accesses: 208737 - Total Traffic: 4.6 GB
CPU Usage: u1.08 s.18 cu0 cs0 - .000854% CPU load
1.41 requests/sec - 32.6 kB/second - 23.0 kB/request
1 requests currently being processed, 9 idle workers

.______W__.._...................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
```

I wonder whether it actually is 256, since the list of requests ranges from 0 to 149. Due to a (yet-to-be-discovered) bug, Apache grinds to a halt with 150 active servers, which matches the `MaxClients` setting. I wonder if the display with 4 rows of 64 characters is misleading and should display 150 characters in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, it seems that the scoreboard is based on the `ServerLimit` instead of `MaxClients`. The Apache documentation is not really explicit about the default value of `ServerLimit` in case of prefork, which turned out to be 256.

Answer (score 0):

apache2 comes, by default (assuming you used `apt-get install apache2`) in Debian Squeeze (6.0) compiled for the Worker MPM model.

if you need or want the prefork MPM model, `apt-get install apache2-mpm-prefork`

the configuration block you are referring to in your question are conditional options for the prefork MPM model, and does not imply the prefork MPM is being used.

[MPM Prefork, too many apache2 process?](https://serverfault.com/questions/244750/mpm-prefork-too-many-apache2-process) is another ServerFault question dealing with similar issues.

you can find the MPM model with: `apache2 -V` or `httpd -V` depending on your distribution.

Comment: OK, I assumed that the MPM I had installed was the default one (can't quite remember switching). Just checked to be sure, so this Apache instance is running prefork. The question I had is separate from the problem I'm facing, in normal circumstances it shouldn't reach 150 and there's a bug out there in some PHP script I guess. I was just wondering about the scoreboard on the status page.