# Command line tools for ping HTTP?

Tags: http, ping, nmap

**Background :** It's a common question as we can search at google "ping works but http does not"

**ping is not a reliable test of network connectivity.**

ping working just means enough of the IP stack is up to process ICMP Echo requests (that's not a huge portion of the system compared to what's required for SSH and web servers). We  could have had what I call a "partial panic" (Kernel blew up, but the IP code kept running), run out of RAM, or our SSH/HTTPd processes could have fallen over for unspecified reasons.

Resources

- [Server not responding to SSH and HTTP but ping works](https://serverfault.com/questions/244712/server-not-responding-to-ssh-and-http-but-ping-works)
- http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/network-internet/403023-ping-works-but-nothing-else-does.html
- https://superuser.com/questions/203667/can-ping-fine-but-no-browsing

**My Question :** Any command line tool for ping HTTP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's plenty of command line tools that are capable of being a command line HTTP or simple TCP client.  `netcat` and `telnet` (and yes, `nmap`) can tell you if the TCP port is responding, and `curl` or `wget` can handle attempting a full HTTP request.

But why not get a real monitoring solution in place instead, if you're having problems with the service failing?

Comment: Would you prefer any real monitoring solution? Please suggest me.

Comment: @MahbuburRAaman There's some good information on monitoring solutions [here](http://serverfault.com/q/394393) and [here](http://serverfault.com/q/44).

Comment: Shane Madden, I have improved my question as your answer.

Answer (score 13):

```
curl --head http://ipaddress/
```

is the closest to a ping, in that it is the minimum check that the server is responding to HTTP requests.

Any monitoring system worth its salt has this functionality built in. Nagios is free IIRC

Comment: If you want to measure the time to connect, you can add some parameters to curl.

`curl --head -s -w %{time_total} om.de`

Answer (score 1):

There is a small program to test performances of a
remote host using TCP packets it's named [echoping](http://echoping.sourceforge.net/). I think that what are you looking for

Comment: That website appears to have been hijacked to redirect to a site offering to "Write College Papers" for a fee.  This may be the current site for that tool, which is unmaintained: https://framagit.org/bortzmeyer/echoping.